# ORACLE SDO_GEOMETRY ToString()?

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-spatial

I have a .Net system that I am writing which needs to be able to retrieve an oracle geometry field from the database. Is there any way in my SQL statement to cast the geometry type to a string so that I can deal with it on my .Net side. At the moment I cannot get the data out as it is not a valid datatype to put into my OLEDB reader so it must be converted database side.

```
select CS_BOUNDS from MDSYS.CS_SRS where SRID = 4326
```

Thanks

Comment: You could use `Get_WKT()` as a temporizing measure.

Comment: How would this be put into the SQL statement shown? Can this be used at the same time as selecting other fields that are not spatial/geometry fields?

Comment: Also using the [latest ODP.Net you can go thru the rigmarole of implementing them as a UDT](http://code.google.com/p/tf-net/wiki/OracleSdoGeometryAsUdt), however, it may not be a nice representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`Get_WKT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objrelschema.htm#CBBDAFFA) method:

> Returns the well-known text (WKT) format (explained in [Section 6.7.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_cs_concepts.htm#i890447)) of a geometry object.

The documentation gives the following example:

```
SELECT c.shape.Get_WKT()
  FROM cola_markets c WHERE c.name = 'cola_b';

C.SHAPE.GET_WKT()                                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POLYGON ((5.0 1.0, 8.0 1.0, 8.0 6.0, 5.0 7.0, 5.0 1.0))
```

The return type is CLOB.

Comment: Thanks. How would this be implemented in the case of my select statement above?

Comment: Your statement would look like `select CS_BOUNDS.Get_WKT() from MDSYS.CS_SRS where SRID = 4326`. With this solution, you will need to parse the resulting string (CLOB is long text) in .Net .

Comment: Ok I will look at implementing that. Thanks.