# How can i import a column type SDO_GEOMETRY from Oracle to HDFS with Sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop, bigdata

**ISSUE**

I'm using Sqoop to fetch data from Oracle and put it to HDFS. Unlike other basic datatypes i understand SDO_GEOMETRY is meant for spatial data.

My Sqoop job fails while fetching datatype SDO_GEOMETRY.

Need help to import the column  Shape with SDO_GEOMETRY datatype from Oracle to Hdfs.

I have more than 1000 tables which has the SDO_GEOMETRY datatype , how can i handle the datatype in general while sqoop imports happen ?

I have tried the --map-column-java and --map-column-hive , but i still get the error.

> **error** :
>   *ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive does not support the SQL type for column
>   SHAPE*

**SQOOP COMMAND**

Below is the sqoop command that i have :

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:oracle:thin:XXXXX/xxxxx@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=xxxxxxx)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxxx)))' -m 1 --create-hive-table --hive-import --fields-terminated-by '^' --null-string '\\\\N' --null-non-string '\\\\N' --hive-overwrite --hive-table PROD.PLAN1   --target-dir test/PLAN1  --table PROD.PLAN  --map-column-hive SE_XAO_CAD_DATA=BINARY --map-column-java SHAPE=String --map-column-hive SHAPE=STRING --delete-target-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The default type mapping that Sqoop provides between relational databases and Hadoop is not working in your case that is why Sqoop Job Fails. You need to override the mapping as geometry datatypes not supported by sqoop.

Use the below parameter in your sqoop job

> syntax:--map-column-java col1=javaDatatype,col2=javaDatatype.....

```
sqoop import
 .......
 ........
 --map-column-java columnNameforSDO_GEOMETRY=String
```

As your column name is Shape

```
--map-column-java Shape=String
```

Comment: When i try --map-column-java columnNameforSDO_GEOMETRY=String , i get the exception saying "No Java type for SQL type 2002 for column SHAPE "

Comment: --map-column-java Shape=String ..try this

Comment: I get this error "ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive does not support the SQL type for column SHAPE"

Comment: Can u share your import command?Just update it in your question

Comment: use --map-column-hive only in your command as it is a hive import

Comment: When i do that i get this error (i removed --map-column-java) : ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type 2002
17/04/07 00:47:42 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 2002 for column

Comment: As your datatype type is complex Sqoop is not able to map it string.So I suggest you make view or temp table in oracle in which convert sdo_geometry to string.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883069/oracle-sdo-geometry-tostring

Comment: Then import this view to hive through sqoop.

Comment: The oracle DB is in Prod and i have only read access to it . So there is no privilege to create view or a temp table in Oracle. --map-column-hive is used to convert complex datatypes right ?

Comment: yes it is supposed to do so,but in your case its not working.

Answer (score 0):

### Sqoop import to HDFS

Sqoop does not support all of the RDBMS datatypes.

If a particular datatype is not supported, you will get error like:

> No Java type for SQL type .....

**Solution**

Add `--map-column-java` in your sqoop command.

Syntax: `--map-column-java col-name=java-type,...`

For example,  `--map-column-java col1=String,col2=String`

### Sqoop import to HIVE

You need same `--map-column-java` mentioned above.

By default, sqoop supports these JDBC types and convert them in the corresponding hive types:

```
 INTEGER 
 SMALLINT 
 VARCHAR 
 CHAR 
 LONGVARCHAR 
 NVARCHAR 
 NCHAR 
 LONGNVARCHAR 
 DATE 
 TIME 
 TIMESTAMP 
 CLOB 
 NUMERIC 
 DECIMAL 
 FLOAT 
 DOUBLE 
 REAL 
 BIT 
 BOOLEAN 
 TINYINT 
 BIGINT
```

If your datatype is not in this list, you get error like:

> Hive does not support the SQL type for .....

**Solution**

You need to add `--map-column-hive` in your sqoop import command.

Syntax: `--map-column-hive col-name=hive-type,...`

For example,  `--map-column-hive col1=string,col2='varchar(100)'`

---

Add `--map-column-java SE_XAO_CAD_DATA=String,SHAPE=String --map-column-hive SE_XAO_CAD_DATA=BINARY,SHAPE=STRING` in your command.

Don't use multiple `--map-column-java` and `--map-column-hive`.

Comment: I tried --map-column-hive but still i get the error : ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type 2002 17/04/07 00:47:42 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 2002 for column.ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.parseNullVal(ClassWriter.java:1377)

Answer (score 0):

For importing SDO GEOMETRY from Oracle to HIVE through SQOOP,
use the [SQOOP free form query option](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/apache-sqoop-cookbook/9781449364618/ch04.html) along with Oracle's [SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-DB459897-729F-41D6-A2F3-DD39F22D8F63), [SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-2AF592C1-7FAB-452F-A276-1F1C09013B97) functions.

The SQOOP --query option allows us to add a SELECT SQL QUERY so that we can get the required data only from the table. And, in the SQL query we can include SDO_UTIL package functions like TO_GEOJSON and TO_WKTGEOMETRY. It looks something like,

```
sqoop import \
...
--query 'SELECT ID, NAME, \
         SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON(MYSHAPECOLUMN), \
         SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(MYSHAPECOLUMN) \
         FROM MYTABLE WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
...
```

This returns the SDO GEOMETRY as Geojson and WKT formats as per the definitions of functions and can directly be inserted into respective HIVE STRING-type columns without any other type mapping in the SQOOP command.

Choose the Geojson and WKT as per requirement and this approach also can be extended to other spatial functions available.